# How to create a database from scratch with macrovariables in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to create a database such as :

```
data seuils_60;
    input seuil1;
    datalines;
    1080
    ;
```

Except that I would like 1080 not to be an actual number, but a value stocked in a macrovariable.
But when I try

```
data seuils_60;
    input seuil1;
    datalines;
    &seuil_60_14
    ;
```

I get an error, although I can `%put` my macrovariable.

What would be the best way around ?

Comment: Macro variable could not be resolved in cards or datalines statement, but it is ok to create table by proc sql.

Comment: You might want to answer the question 'why are you doing this', as the answer to that might lead to a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Just use an assignment statement.

```
data seuils_60;
  seuil1=&seuil_60_14;
run;
```